# Install pyqt via homebrew with `--with-python3` but still goes to Python 2

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, homebrew

Here's my command and output (some command line arguments are left out). What is going wrong? Thank you.

```
$ brew reinstall pyqt --with-python3
==> Reinstalling pyqt --with-python3
==> Downloading http://downloads.sf.net/project/pyqt/PyQt4/PyQt-4.10.3/PyQt-mac-
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/pyqt-4.10.3.tar.gz
==> Patching
patching file configure.py
==> python configure.py --confirm-license --bindir=/usr/local/Cellar/pyqt/4.10.3
==> python ./configure-ng.py --confirm-license --bindir=/usr/local/Cellar/pyqt/4
==> make
==> make install
==> Caveats
Set PYTHONPATH if you want Python to find your site-packages:
  export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/pyqt/4.10.3: 560 files, 18M, built in 6.6 minutes
```

**UPDATE**:
I think the formula of `pyqt` somehow hard-codes the python's version. For example it explicitly includes paths like `python2.7/site-packages/`. Here's part of the file:

```
  def install
    # On Mavericks we want to target libc++, this requires a non default qt makespec
    if ENV.compiler == :clang and MacOS.version >= :mavericks
      ENV.append "QMAKESPEC", "unsupported/macx-clang-libc++"
    end

    args = [ "--confirm-license",
             "--bindir=#{bin}",
             "--destdir=#{lib}/python2.7/site-packages",
             "--sipdir=#{share}/sip" ]
    # We need to run "configure.py" so that pyqtconfig.py is generated, which
    # is needed by PyQWT (and many other PyQt interoperable implementations such
    # as the ROS GUI libs). This file is currently needed for generating build
    # files appropriate for the qmake spec that was used to build Qt. This method
    # is deprecated and will be removed with SIP v5, so we do the actual compile
    # using the newer configure-ng.py as recommended.
    system "python", "configure.py", *args
    (lib/'python2.7/site-packages').install 'pyqtconfig.py'

    # On Mavericks we want to target libc++, this requires a non default qt makespec
    if ENV.compiler == :clang and MacOS.version >= :mavericks
      args << "--spec" << "unsupported/macx-clang-libc++"
    end

    system "python", "./configure-ng.py", *args
    system "make"
    system "make", "install"
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

You should check out this issue on Homebrew's git: 
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/25735

We can no longer use the --with-python3 argument with pyside/pyqt/sip. Unfortunately, it seems like we can't use Homebrew for these modules in a while. They probably have to find another solution of handling the formulas for having Python 2.7 and Python3 installs first.

I scratched my head for days figuring this out. Ended up with installing PyQt from source.

Good luck.

Comment: Happily, this has been fixed! As of this writing, installing pyqt with --with-python3 works correctly.

Comment: As of this writing, `--with-python3` does not work. But `--without-python` works.