# Python 3 can't find homebrew pyqt installation

Tags: python, homebrew

I recently used homebrew to install pyqt (along with qt & sip), but get an import error whenever I try to import PyQt4 in Python 3 (which was also installed using homebrew). To confuse matters more, I *am* able to import PyQt4 on Python 2 via the terminal.

I'm totally new to working with Python packages and, with that, totally confused. Any thoughts on how I might be able to undo what I did and reinstall so that I can access PyQt via the usr/local/python3 installation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be seperatelibrary files for python2 and python3. From your question, it seems that you have installed pyqt for python2 which you can't import in python3.

For python3, you have to install specific package developed for python3.

Here is a similar question regarding python3 pyqt installation using homebrew. <strike>It says, there is currently some limitation with homebrew.
[Install pyqt via homebrew with `--with-python3` but still goes to Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956517/install-pyqt-via-homebrew-with-with-python3-but-still-goes-to-python-2)</strike>
EDIT:
Developer of homebrew has resolved the issue.

Comment: "It says, there is currently some limitation with homebrew." FWIW, this was true when it was written but is no longer accurate; this should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

`brew reinstall pyqt --with-python3` will get you sorted!